# Spark sum by key without reducing rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD with the following structure:

```
(lang, id, name, max, min)
```

I want to add another column, `total`, which holds the subtraction of the maximum value of column `max` and the minimum of column `min` for every unique `lang` (without reducing the amount of rows). So I would get something like

```
rdd:
+----+--+----+---+---+
|lang|id|name|max|min|
+----+--+----+---+---+
|  en|  |    |  5|  1|
|  en|  |    |  2|  0|
|  de|  |    |  9|  2|
|  en|  |    |  7|  1|
|  nl|  |    |  3|  0|
|  nl|  |    |  5|  1|
+----+--+----+---+---+
```

To

```
rdd:
+----+--+----+---+---+-----+
|lang|id|name|max|min|total|
+----+--+----+---+---+-----+
|  en|  |    |  5|  1|    7|
|  en|  |    |  2|  0|    7|
|  de|  |    |  9|  2|    7|
|  en|  |    |  7|  1|    7|
|  nl|  |    |  3|  0|    5|
|  nl|  |    |  5|  1|    5|
+----+--+----+---+---+-----+
```

For compatibility reasons, I want to achieve this **without** using DataFrames/Spark SQL.

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: for lang = en , max of column max = 7 and min of column min = 0 , so the total should be 7 - 0 = 7 and not 6. Please review your output and correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("en", "id1", "name1", 5,  1), ("en", "id2", "name2", 2,  0), 
  ("de", "id3", "name3", 9,  2), ("en", "id4", "name4", 7,  1),
  ("nl", "id5", "name5", 3,  0), ("nl", "id6", "name6", 5,  1)
))

val totals = rdd.keyBy(_._1).aggregateByKey((Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue))(
  { case ((maxA, minA), (_, _, _, maxX, minX)) => 
    (Math.max(maxA, maxX), Math.min(minA, minX)) }, 
  { case ((maxA1, minA1), (maxA2, minA2)) => 
    (Math.max(maxA1, maxA2), Math.min(minA1, minA2))}
).mapValues { case (max, min) => max - min }
```

join with the original data:

```
val vals = rdd.keyBy(_._1).join(totals).values
```

and flatten (with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)):

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

val result = vals.map { case (x, y) => x :+ y }

result.toDF.show
```

with an output:

```
+---+---+-----+---+---+---+ 
| _1| _2|   _3| _4| _5| _6|
+---+---+-----+---+---+---+
| en|id1|name1|  5|  1|  7|
| en|id2|name2|  2|  0|  7|
| en|id4|name4|  7|  1|  7|
| de|id3|name3|  9|  2|  7|
| nl|id5|name5|  3|  0|  5|
| nl|id6|name6|  5|  1|  5|
+---+---+-----+---+---+---+
```

but for complex aggregations this becomes tedious, inefficient, and hard to manage pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform two operation on your RDD

**1.Reducebykey**

**2.Join**

```
 val rdd = originalRDD.rdd.map(row => 
 (row(0), (row(1).toString.toLong, row(2).toString.toLong))
 )
```

Apply **reducebyKey** and get the min and max values of each lang

```
val filterRDD = jsonRdd.reduceByKey(minMax).map(row => (row._1, (row._2._1-row._2._2)))

  def minMax(a: Tuple2[Long, Long], b: Tuple2[Long, Long]):Tuple2[Long,Long] = {
  val min = if (a._1 < b._1) a._1 else b._1
  val max = if (a._2 > b._2) a._2 else b._2
  (min, max)
  }
```

Apply **join** condition

```
 rdd.join(filterRDD).map(row => (row._1, row._2._1._1, row._2._1._2, row._2._2))
```